# Find files in project/solution that no longer exist

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2010 has a bug (or annoying behavior) that it always starts a new build for a project if it includes a reference to a (source) file that no longer exists (and subsequently all depending projects). Now I have a rather large project and the only way I know of to find such files is to manually open every file.

Is there an easier way to identify such invalid references in project files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a python script that identifies missing files and prints them to the console.

```
import os
import re
import sys

def show_help():
    print()
    print("Syntax:", sys.argv[0], "[filename]")
    print()

def check_missing_project_includes(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    p = re.compile('(ClCompile|ClInclude) Include="(.*?)" />', re.IGNORECASE)

    missing_files = []
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(p, line)
        if m:
            filename = m.group(2)
            if not os.path.exists(filename):
                missing_files.append(filename)

    return missing_files



if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    show_help()
    exit()

filename = sys.argv[1]
missing_files = check_missing_project_includes(filename)

if len(missing_files) > 0:
    print("Missing files:")
    for mf in missing_files:
        print("\t", mf)
```

Answer (score 0):

A technique that I've used to diagnose missing files is to install a SCC provider Addin (eg AnkhSVN if you're using Subversion), then in the Solution Explorer missing files will have a different icon.  This isn't as useful for larger projects, but for smaller ones it's quite quick to see at a glance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried opening the proj file in an editor like Notepad++ and locate and remove the references from there? (If I'm understanding the question correctly that is)

Comment: The problem is not removing the references but if I delete a file without removing the reference, VS does not tell me about it but instead always starts a new build even if nothing has changed.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fc504cc6-5808-4da8-ae86-8d3f9ed81606

Comment: I think this extension only applies to referenced assemblies but not source files that have been deleted.